# dont´ count padding on :hover image

Tags: hover

i´m making image gallery. I have placed images inside unordered list. I set padding around images and than I tried to create hover effect only throught image (without padding) so i´ve used the calc() function. here is website

http://rpz.startupweb.sk/vyrobky/

but how you can see hover effect doesn´t cover whole image. Whole image have black overlay but on some edges you can see white line. Could you help me and write what´s wrong or write right procedure. Thanks a lot

CODE FOR UNORDERED LIST:

```
ul.thumbnail {
position: relative;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

ul.thumbnail li {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 23.5%;
cursor: pointer;
}

ul.thumbnail li img {
position: relative;
max-width: 100%;
padding: 1.875em;
}
```

CODE FOR HOVER EFFECT

```
.parent {
width: calc(100% - 3.75em);
height: calc(100% - 3.75em);
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
display: block;
background-color: black;
opacity: 0;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-align: center;
transition: opacity 500ms;
-webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
-moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
-o-transition: opacity 500ms;
}

span.parent span {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
top: 25%;
}

 ul.thumbnail li:hover span.parent{
opacity: 0.7;
}

.parent-icon {
padding: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose within a Div block will bring ur solution

```
`HTML`
<li>
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="" alt="thumb_5f">
        <span class="parent">
           <span class="parent-icon"></span>
        </span>
    <div>
</li>
`CSS`
.img-container{
   possition: relative;
}
ul.thumbnail li img{ padding: 0px; }
ul.thumbnail li{ padding: 30px; }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your helps. It seems it´s much better. I created media query and there is same problem overlay doesn´t cover whole image (you can see white line on the bottom). So i tried to change height of .parent element from 100% to 100.5%. It´s right or is better way how fix it? thx

Comment: its not the perfect solution

Comment: Why is the empty line still at the image:hover. How can i fix it better? thx

Comment: ul.thumbnail li { width : 25.7%; } try this